# from the zip file not able to fetch data from the document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ssziparchive

i am downloading a zip file and saving in document directory. and then making unzip using the [ssziparchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) . but not getting any data from the zip file .how to fetch the data .and i am not able to see where is my unzip file .in document directory only i am getting this.
[image]

i have used this code to make zip as un zip file

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.zip"];
    NSString *zipPath =fullPath;
    NSString *destinationPath =[documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"unZipimage"];
    NSLog(@"zip path==%@",zipPath);
    NSLog(@"dest path==%@",destinationPath);
  //
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip Data store in Bundle To document directory as below.

1. get Path from Bundle.

   ```
    NSString *StrZIP = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestZIP" ofType:@"zip"];
   ```
2. convert `Zip` To `NSData`

   ```
   NSData *ZIPData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:StrZIP];
   ```
3. Store Zip file in document directory

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
   NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestZIP.zip"]; //Add the file name
   [ZIPData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
   ```
4. TeztZIP is unzip using `SSZipArchive` at documentsPath

   ```
   [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:filePath toDestination:documentsPath];
   ```

OUTPUT :

[image]

Comment: Its working for me in my project, may your code have some mistake. Check your code.

Comment: my zip file inside Library

Comment: check  my zip file  saved in NSCachesDirectory .in Library ->caches->image.its not showing in unzip in document or in NSCachesDirectory

Comment: finally  i have changed my image.zip location .NSCachesDirectory to document then its working but my requirement is not like that .