# Unzip Files in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, php-ziparchive

I have a .zip folder which contains some images. I want it to unzip into Documents directory in iOS device. I tried with the following link,

[download and unzip file in iOS-Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333399/download-and-unzip-file-in-ios)
Here is the code that I tried in my app,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                     YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Obj.zip"];
ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filepath Password:@""];
[zipArchive UnzipFileTo:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Obj"] overWrite:YES];
[zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];
```

And then I printed the all files in `Document Directory`, but the `Obj.zip` is the only file(Obj.zip is the file that wants to unzip) that exist in the Documents Directory. How can I done this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: check My answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060790/from-the-zip-file-not-able-to-fetch-data-from-the-document-directory

Comment: I tried. but documnet directory has only the obj.zip file

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333399/download-and-unzip-file-in-ios

Comment: Yes checked. But same output. no file is out there..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use SSZipArchive. Here is a sample code. https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive

Also I believe the unzipping would create a folder in documents directory which would contain the files. Please check that

```
NSString *zipPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:zipFileName ofType:@"zip"];
NSString *destinationPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath];
```

**Update** : Get zip file from documents directory

```
NSString *filename = @"MyZipFile.zip";
NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * zipPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

NSString *destinationPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath];
```

Comment: My file is not in main bundle. It's also in Documents directory